# Daily report on SharePoint

Tags: list, reporting

I've got a list with ~2000 items.  I'm hoping to add a daily status update (i.e. Up/Down) to each that i can then use the results to make monthly/yearly/etc.. trend charts.  Is there a clean way to do this without lists getting out of control large?

edit: 
To keep it simple, I don't really need to know how to get the data, just wondering on the best way of setting it up.  Lets say I have a thermometer and each day I want someone to check that and add the value to that item on the list (therm. 1) but have access to all the previous values for trending.  Now i have 2000 thermometers, what would be a good way to track all that data?  All I can come up with is versioning, I'm not sure that would be the best way.

Thanks,

Chuck

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific on what you are trying to accomplish exactly? Exporting to excel would be a way to create some linked graphs etc. Can you articulate the requirement a little bit further?

Comment: Thanks Kyle,  Edited for a little more clarity hopefully.

Answer (score 0):

One option here would be to create a simple workflow that on "edit" would copy the list item to a new "tracking" list, make sure to have a column to track the "Title" and the "Updated Value", you can then group a view on your "tracking list" and then it would allow you to easily see the trend over time etc by grouping/sorting/modified etc.

You could then edit the page for the original list and link the webparts together creating a type of "dashboard". It's beyond the scope of this answer but you should be able to link them together

Would this be an option for you?